# How can I define a variable can will hold the type of a generic protocol in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I want to create a method that takes a type of a class that implements a generic protocol and then hold that value in a variable, so that later I can create instances.

Example with non-generic protocol

```
protocol Initializable { init() }

class Impl: Initializable { required init(){} }

//Here we will hold the type of a class that implements Initializable
var initializableType: Initializable.Type? = nil

//This method will get the type of a class that implements Initializable and store it to initializableType.
func register<T>(implementation: T.Type) where T : Initializable {
    initializableType = implementation.self
}

//Register the type
register(implementation: Impl.self)

//Then create instance
initializableType?.init()
```

Now how I can to do the same for the following protocol?

```
protocol GenericInitializable {
    associatedtype InitDataType

    init(_ with: InitDataType)
}
```

It seems I can not define a type that will hold the meta type of a generic protocol. The type erasure technique works for instances, and as the name suggest it erases the type information that I need.

Comment: You are right. You can't do this. How will the compiler know the actual type of `InitDataType` of the type instance you are storing?

Comment: Well I could modify the register method to pass the InitDataType, so the compiler will know, but there is no language feature that I have found that can use it. For example if I could define generic closures I would store the init implementation(or all the protocol methods) in a wrapper class. What I am asking is if there is a known workaround.

Comment: Known workaround to achieve what? If this worked the way you wanted it, what would the calling code look like. Please actually write the code you would want to type in place for `register` and `initializableType?.init()` and have compile. What would you pass to `init(_ with: InitDataType)`? A slightly more concrete example may help us get you on the right road. I'm assuming that `Initializable` is just for example; it's a useless protocol, so I'm assuming you have a more useful protocol in mind.

Comment: Slightly related note: your `<T>` in `register<T>` is unnecessary and possibly causing some confusion. The better version is `func register(implementation: Initializable.Type) { initializableType = implementation }`